# Controller As syntax with search input form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Built a small search app with AngularJS and Elasticsearch and I'm trying to convert from using `$scope` to `controller As` syntax because it seems like a very good thing to do and highly recommended.

Really simple app with home and search results page. Home has searchbox with autocomplete and results page the same thing with space for results.

I'm using UI Router for my routes/states:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl as home'})
  .state('search', {
    url: '/search?q',
    views: {
      '' : {templateUrl: 'search/search.html',
            controller: 'SearchCtrl as search'}
    }
  });
```

And to replace the `$scope` service in my controllers, I did

```
    'use strict';

angular.module("searchApp.autocomplete", ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$sce', '$state', '$stateParams', 'searchService', 'filterService', function($sce, $state, $stateParams, searchService, filterService) {

    var vm = this;...
```

and replaced all `$scope.` with `vm.` for both controllers.

I've added the `ng-controller="SomeCtrl as some"` in a div for each template in the html files but for some reason I can not get the app to work now.

My links still work (ui-sref) so I can navigate between pages, but the autocomplete and search functionality is gone. When I check the console in Chrome dev tools, it says

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: searchTerms is not defined(…)
```

But I have `vm.searchTerms = $stateParams.q || null;`  right after the var vm = this; in the controllers.

searchTerms is my ng-model on the

Everything was pretty much working until I tried to convert over to `controller As` syntax. What exactly am I doing wrong because it seems like its pretty simple.

**UPDATE**
As requested, my template code

```
    <form ng-submit="search()" class="form-horizontal col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="hp-search-form">
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <input type="text" name="q" ng-model="searchTerms" placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-lg" id="search-input" uib-typeahead="query for query in getSuggestions($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="search($item)" auto-focus>

      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" id="hp-search-button" ng-submit="search()">Search
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
<a ui-sref="search">Search Page</a>
```

Comment: remove ng-controller="SomeCtrl as some" from all template.

Comment: @SSH did that, but still doesn't work

Comment: can you put template code?

Comment: provide template code

Comment: ok, give a minute and I'll include it in an UPDATE

Comment: @SSH ok, added template in UPDATE above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. you should add controllerAs(search in this template) before all models and functions in your template.

```
<input type="text" name="q" ng-model="search.searchTerms" placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-lg" id="search-input" uib-typeahead="query for query in search.getSuggestions($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="search.search($item)" auto-focus>
```

Comment: still getting the error in Uncaught Reference error in the console, any other ideas?

Comment: didn't solve the problem, but pointed me in the right direction!